# How to strongly bind DB table to Datatable in ADO.Net - WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am learning WPF and I want to know how can I strongly bind a DataTable to a DB Table. Below is what I have till now.

**DB Tables:**

a. tblTenant

b. tblUnit

Steps I performed till now.
I added a `XSD file` and connected Server Explorer to my SSMS DB.
Then Dragged both the table to the XSD window. Below is what I got.

[image]

Now I named the file as DataSet1. Then below is the code I wrote.

```
  public static void GetDataFromDB()
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblTenant; Select * from tblUnit;", con);
                DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();
                da.Fill(ds1);

            }
```

**Current Output:**

I see 4 tables in `ds1`

1. Table : It has tblTenant data from DB
2. Table2: It has tblUnit data from DB
3. tblTenant: It is empty
4. tblUnit: It is empty

**Expected Output:**

Just 2 datatables

1. tblTenant: Should have tblTenant data from DB.
2. tblUnit: Should have tblUnit data from DB.

[image]

**WORKAROUND:**

```
  public static void GetDataFromDB()
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblTenant; Select * from tblUnit;", con);
                //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();
                ds1.tblTenant.Merge(ds.Tables[0]);
                ds1.tblUnit.Merge(ds.Tables[1]);
            }
        }
```

But I don't think this is the right way. Please guide me.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with EF or WPF. I've removed the irrelevant tags. You *really* should learn EF Code First approach. At this point even an EF DB Scaffolding would be an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are generating a dataset based on tables from a datasource, you are creating a typed dataset. To fill a typed dataset, you need to specify the datatable you are filling when you are calling fill method of the data adapter, if not a default table will be filled and added. But, with this you will not be able to specify multiple sql select statements to retrieve multiple tables like you have done. A good practice would be to create a command per table.

```
var command = con.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select * from tblTenant";
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
var ds1 = new DataSet1();
da.Fill(ds1, "tblTenant");
```